# How to add line breaks to plotly hover labels

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to get plotly to display the hover text on multiple lines/get it to recognize special characters line '\n' in the text?

A dummy version of what I'm looking to do is:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(10, 8), rnorm(10, 2)))
names(data)<-c("thing1", "thing2")

data$hovertext <- paste("here's a coordinate: ",
                         round(data$thing1,1), sep = "\n")


p <- plot_ly(data, type = 'scatter', x = thing1, y = thing2, 
             text = hovertext, hoverinfo = 'text', mode = "markers")
```

Which of course just ignores the separator and prints all on one line. Can I trick plotly/R into recognizing that line break?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just use the HTML tag `<br>`:

```
library(plotly)
data <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(10, 8), rnorm(10, 2)))
names(data) <- c("thing1", "thing2")

data$hovertext <- paste("here's a coordinate:",
                     round(data$thing1,1), sep = "<br>")


p <- plot_ly(data, type = 'scatter', x = ~thing1, y = ~thing2, 
         text = ~hovertext, hoverinfo = 'text', mode = "markers")
```

Additionally, you could use HTML tags to change the font styles as well (and much more)...

Comment: Just want to add: make sure to use `<br>` and *not* `<br/>` – the latter will not work.

Comment: `<br>`, `<br />`, and `<br/>` are three different tags; the first two work, the third will not

Comment: @Martin: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242473/r-adding-a-tool-tip-to-interactive-plot-plotly Thanks!