# How to add line breaks to all existing hover texts in a plotly figure

Tags: python, plotly

I am computing a plotly figure in an external library, ie I have a function that return a fig object.

However, the hover texts are very long and i want to add line breaks. How can I do that?

The entire code is not so easy to reproduce, but I am using this:

```py
import textwrap
from bertopic import BERTopic
from umap import UMAP
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

docs = [
  # ...
]
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
embeddings = model(docs)

topic_model = BERTopic()
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs, embeddings)

reduced_embeddings = UMAP(n_neighbors=10, n_components=2, min_dist=0.0, metric='cosine').fit_transform(embeddings)
fig = topic_model.visualize_documents(docs, reduced_embeddings=reduced_embeddings, width=1920, height=1080)

def wrap_text(text, delimiter='<br>', after=80):
  if text is None:
    return text
  return textwrap.fill(text, width=80).replace('\n', delimiter)

fig.update_traces(
    text=[wrap_text(text) for text in fig.data[0].hovertext],
    hoverinfo='text'
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add line breaks to plotly hover labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878695/how-to-add-line-breaks-to-plotly-hover-labels)

Comment: @Sheldon, No, it's R not python.

Comment: Good point @timbmg. I retracted my vote to close the answer.

Comment: Whether it's r or python or js or julia, the answer is the same. The problem is you assign the wrapped hovertext to text instead of hovertext. You could also wrap the label directly.